# Restrict Login Subscriber users from accessing frontend

Tags: front-end, content-restriction

I’m running a private site login users have access to the front-end using [My Private Site plugin][1] However I would like to restrict subscribers users who are login from accessing frontend and keep them on the admin dashboard (backend)

any Functionality I can use to add on the theme function file to restrict subscribe from accessing front-end based on user roles?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-content/ is a kind of solution. Check out.

Comment: That plugin only restrict users from reading content pages or posts it's a membership  plugin. What i'm looking is restrick subscriber from accessing frontend if the subscriber trys to go to frontend example www.yousite.com it will direct them back to the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Hello :) I'm a newbie but I think this will help you a bit at least... Please coorect me if there are any mistakes :) **I didn't test this code**

`// Block subscribers from accessing the WordPress front-end
function wpabsolute_block_users_frontend() {
    if ( !is_admin() && ! current_user_can( ! 'administrator' ) && ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
        wp_redirect( *url u want to redirect* );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpabsolute_block_users_frontend' );`